Waffle diagram with custom icon in Power BI
I would like to personalize my waffle diagram in Power BI with the following SVG code (copied from https://www.svgviewer.dev/s/65380/waffle):


I tried to paste in a new Table in Power BI in 1 cell (Column1/row1) just the part which should be enough (from the section path d=):
M456.348,0H55.652C24.966,0,0,24.966,0,55.652v400.696C0,487.034,24.966,512,55.652,512h400.696C487.034,512,512,487.034,512,456.348V55.652C512,24.966,487.034,0,456.348,0z M122.545,478.609H55.652c-12.275,0-22.261-9.986-22.261-22.261v-66.893h89.154V478.609z M122.545,356.175H33.391v-83.59h89.154V356.175z M122.545,239.305H33.391v-83.59h89.154V239.305z M122.545,122.436H33.391V55.652c0-12.275,9.986-22.261,22.261-22.261h66.893V122.436z M239.415,478.609h-83.59v-89.154h83.59V478.609z M239.415,356.175h-83.59v-83.59h83.59V356.175z M239.415,239.305h-83.59v-83.59h83.59V239.305z M239.415,122.436h-83.59V33.391h83.59V122.436z M356.284,478.609h-83.59v-89.154h83.59V478.609z M356.284,356.175h-83.59v-83.59h83.59V356.175z M356.284,239.305h-83.59v-83.59h83.59V239.305z M356.284,122.436h-83.59V33.391h83.59V122.436z M478.609,456.348c0,12.275-9.986,22.261-22.261,22.261h-66.784v-89.154h89.045V456.348z M478.609,356.175h-89.045v-83.59h89.045V356.175z M478.609,239.305h-89.045v-83.59h89.045V239.305z M478.609,122.436h-89.045V33.391h66.784c12.275,0,22.261,9.986,22.261,22.261V122.436z
But I keep getting error when getting that cell to the Visualizations/Category data/Paths. Can somebody suggest a solution to solve this?
Thanks in advance.
